# Result filter and pagination in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I need some help or an idea for the correct procedure.
I already indexed a big vaste of documents. Now I found out that there are some documents with almost the same content, f.e.

```
{
  "title": "myDocument",
  "date": "2017-09-18",
  "page": 1
}

{
  "title": "myDocument",
  "date": "2017-09-18",
  "page": 2
}
```

The title field is mapped as text, date is date and page is integer. As you can see the only difference is the page value.
Now I want to make a query and filter out these duplicates. Field collapsing seems a good way to do it but in this case I can't get the correct count of results and that's important for me.
An other way would be to get all results first and then filter out "manually" but then I have a problem with pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
GET index/type/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "count_by_title_date_page":{
      "terms": {
        "field": "title.keyword",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "date": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "date.keyword",
            "size": 100
          },
          "aggs": {
            "page": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "page.keyword",
                "size": 100
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok and then I will get the correct number of total hits? For example if I set size=10 and from=11 because I want to get results for the "second page"?

Comment: Aggregation is applied on all the documents in your index and not just on first 10 documents. You are mixing search with aggregation. Aggregation is performed on whole. This above query will give you page counts of each page based on its title & date. It is like group by title, date, page in terms of Sql.